# Laravel orderBy() function does not work for eagerly loaded model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables as,

**foos(a,b,c)**

**bars(e,f,g)**

In the controllers I am using,
$foos = Foo::with('Bar');

Now to sort the values with b as ascending I can write,

```
$foos = Foo::with('Bar')->orderBy('b', 'asc')->get();
```

However, sorting is not working for the fields that are part of eagerly loaded models, for example this code is not sorting anything. What might be the reason?

```
$foos = Foo::with(array('Bar' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('g', 'desc');
}))->get();
```

Comment: I recommend you to install debugbar (find on github/packalyst) and see queries yourself. You can sort collection if I am not mistaken.